# POST with curl gives correct output but with AJAX gives an error

Tags: php, html, ajax, post, forms

I am quite frustrated with a very weird issue. I am trying to do a very simple thing here. I would like to post a form to an endpoint. I tried using the following command:

```
 curl -d "Contact=Aditya&address1=1510 E. 9th Street&address2=Apt. 111&city=Tucson&state=AZ&zip=85719&Phone1=5207849817&Phone2=1237849812&email=aditya15417@yahoo.com&key2=09 New Lead&key5=AmpushU&uhsgradyr=1950&uhighlevel=AA&ucourseint=BA Internet Mktg&uCampaignID=Herlambang&utextperm=YES&uleaddate=20110910&uleadtime=19:18 PST" http://dev.degreeamerica.com/candidate_test.php
```

And yes it succeeds just fine, however when I try it via the [site](http://www.adityaherlambang.com) it gives me an error. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? The parameter I have on the curl is just something I copy and paste from firebug POST request, so the parameter is all the same.
Is there something wrong with me doing the AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't receive the results of a cross-domain post like that.  Your page is on adityaherlambang.com, but you're posting to degreeamerica.com, so you can't get the results

One solution is to use a server-side proxy on adityaherlambang.com, and post using [libcurl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to degreeamerica.com, while returning whatever kind of status you want to your own site's JavaScript.

Comment: you're saying that I can't post on a domain other than what my page is hosted on? any other easier alternative than that?

Comment: also why is it that if it's not an AJAX but just a regular submit action post then I can see the results?

Comment: also by server-side proxy meaning that I have to change the degreeamerica.com?

Comment: You can POST, but you can't get the results.  If it were a regular POST, code on adityaherlambang.com wouldn't be able to see the result.  I'll clarify my answer.